# Media Queries not displayed any output on Ipad application

Tags: android, css, mobile, media-queries

I have added my media Queries and seems when i run under this [site](http://old.isresponsive.com/) it does not displayed the right output i expected..This is the First test i did for this mobile

this is my media Queries

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px), (min-device-width: 768px) and
(max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    .wrap{
        width:95%;
        }

     .box{
     width:29.33%;
      float:left;
      margin:0px 42px 0px 0
    }   

    html{
        background-color:red;
    }
}
```

I did a troubleshot on body and html however the background color not displayed

this is my [site](http://www.hideawayholidays.com.au/ASP/nan_cost_naviti.asp)

My CSS

```
.wrap{
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.box{
    width: 29.33%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Where is your site at? Post a link, If not post all of the css code and then the html code too.

Comment: i have updated my question and my site link is there..if you need a CSS i can send it also

Comment: add a Css also.its been included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have added my media Queries

But you've forgotten a key ingredient in media queries, which is the meta viewport element. E.g.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

You need to place that in the `head` of your pages for media queries to operate.

Answer (score 0):

In your html file you have

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
```

That's older, I would replace it with html5 doctype

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

BTW that place looks nice.

Comment: Thanks Mate.changed it.i hope you like my site..;)

Comment: Fyi if i removed the "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">" It will looks different in chrome...after removed and add a gain my site looks good in chrome..so i leave as it  is

Comment: No, if you want change that and save your original page as index2.html. Then open both and view them side by side.

Comment: Thanks..i cleared cache in chrome..have removed as what you  told above, it looks nice

Comment: that's great to hear